# Alexa audio skill show progress bar while playing audio

Tags: node.js, progress-bar, alexa-skills-kit, audio-player

I am sending audio player directive like:

```
handlerInput.responseBuilder
    .addAudioPlayerPlayDirective('REPLACE_ALL', podcastURL, podcastURL, 0, null, metadata)
    .getResponse();
```

Audio is playing in Echo Show but no progress bar or playtime information is visible on the screen.

Try **Alexa play music** in echo show for reference. There is a progress bar showing the playtime of audio content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE: The pre-built [Music/Radio](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/music-skills/understand-the-music-skill-api.html) Interaction Model is required to get the scrubber. No word yet on if/when the scrubber will also be available to the Custom Interaction Model: AudioPlayer interface.**

---

Nope; you're not doing anything wrong, it's just not there.

We've used AudioPlayer extensively (for years). I've never seen the timeline on our responses either.

*Heads up. You'll probably get dinged by someone if you don't throw a question in there somewhere.*

Comment: I have also seen a progress bar in Apple Podcast skill.

Comment: Sure enough. The it is. My guess would be they're a managed partner and have special privileges. Docs explicitly say controls include pause, previous, and next. https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html#touch-controls

Comment: I'm going to reach out to our contact and see if I can get an official answer on this.

Comment: I will be very grateful @Timothy

Comment: Haven't forgotten about you. I'm being told "it's being looked into".

Comment: Updated the answer: Music/Radio Interaction Model is required.